# Bootstrap not loading in firefox but working in all other browsers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, cross-browser

My problem is not a regular cross browser issue. Its kind of wierd.

I have a plugin which can be integrated on some client sites(right now integrated only one client).

My plugin uses bootstrap for front end. When the client opens my plugin in chrome it works perfect but when the same plugin is opened from firefox client has css issues as bootstrap is not getting loaded.

The weird thing here is when I open the client site from my firefox(same version as client's 43.0.4) , the plugin works fine for me but client is having issues. I asked them to try force reload(Cntl+Shift+R) and private mode, but no use.

Client's country is Switzerland. I thought may be bootstrap is not accessible from their country so removed CDN and hosted the bootstrap css file in my server and referred the css link locally by using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

({{ STATIC_URL }} here is Django's syntax for referring local static files). But the issue is not solved.

I m repeating again the plugin is working fine in my firefox but not in client's.

Any help would definitely be appreciated.

**Edit:**
here is the link for the client site : http://www.viartbd-boutique.com/en/9-eve-ferrigutti

the plugin is integrated on fourth apparel
It is plugin called dressy which enables a user to try any apprel virtually and by the user measurements given it will suggest a size in that particular brand which fits good for the user. for more information of the plugin you can visit: http://dres.sy/

Thank you.

Comment: try to clear clients browser cache. that might help

Comment: can you provide the link of that site? can we check it as well?

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz  I ve edited the post and you can find the links there. Thank you for your response.

Comment: i'left work and on my way to home. I'll take a look as soon as possible

Comment: Did You test it? @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz